# Is it possible to "stream" a terminal application with python?

Tags: python, terminal, streaming

I'm making a project and I want to make a terminal frontend for it, in case the web version stops working. It's a collection of tools that can all be ran on a terminal, however, I would like to be able to code a client that just gets whatever options are available, so that updating or running the whole program becomes unneccesary.

I can easily write the complete app as a terminal application. I've never made anything that really streams data though, as far as I know. So I'm curious if this is possible.

Comment: where do you want to stream that data? considering you are producing it, you don't need to first get if from the terminal, you can directly put it wherever you need, are you looking for a web framework or what?

Comment: It would come from a server and go to a terminal client, yes. The client will contain just the basic login functionality, and the code for sending and receiving+displaying the information the user needs.

Comment: and where exactly are you stuck? some more details would be great. if you ask about whether it is possible, I would say yes, there really is little that is not possible with software